# How to make the f# compiler (fsc) verbose?

Tags: f#

I have a small or average sized F# project, 15 *.fs files, about 2000 lines of code. It suddenly got a bit slow to compile, about 5 seconds. I would like to find out what makes compilation slow, but cannot find switch for fsc like "verbose" that causes it to show progress information.

Anybody knows how to trace the F# compiler **fsc** to get an idea where to tune compilation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`--times`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/dd233171.aspx) switch "displays timing information for compilation". It displays very detailed information and should help you figure out what's taking so long

Compiling the following program

```
open System

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    printfn "Hello World" 
    Console.ReadLine() |> ignore
    0
```

produces this output

```
Microsoft (R) F# Compiler version 12.0.30110.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All Rights Reserved.

TIME:  0.1 Delta:  0.0 Mem:  34 G0:   0 G1:  0 G2:  0 [Import mscorlib]
TIME:  0.1 Delta:  0.0 Mem:  35 G0:   0 G1:  0 G2:  0 [Import mscorlib and FSharp.Core.dll]
TIME:  0.4 Delta:  0.3 Mem:  60 G0:   5 G1:  3 G2:  1 [Import system references]
TIME:  0.4 Delta:  0.0 Mem:  64 G0:   1 G1:  1 G2:  0 [Parse inputs]
TIME:  0.4 Delta:  0.0 Mem:  64 G0:   0 G1:  0 G2:  0 [Import non-system references]
TIME:  0.5 Delta:  0.1 Mem:  68 G0:   1 G1:  1 G2:  0 [Typecheck]
TIME:  0.5 Delta:  0.0 Mem:  68 G0:   0 G1:  0 G2:  0 [Typechecked]
TIME:  0.5 Delta:  0.0 Mem:  69 G0:   0 G1:  0 G2:  0 [Write Interface File]
TIME:  0.5 Delta:  0.0 Mem:  69 G0:   0 G1:  0 G2:  0 [Write XML document signatures]
TIME:  0.5 Delta:  0.0 Mem:  69 G0:   0 G1:  0 G2:  0 [Write XML docs]
TIME:  0.5 Delta:  0.0 Mem:  69 G0:   0 G1:  0 G2:  0 [Write HTML docs]
TIME:  0.6 Delta:  0.1 Mem:  73 G0:   2 G1:  1 G2:  1 [Encode Interface Data]
TIME:  0.7 Delta:  0.1 Mem:  76 G0:   1 G1:  1 G2:  0 [Optimizations]
TIME:  0.7 Delta:  0.0 Mem:  77 G0:   0 G1:  0 G2:  0 [Ending Optimizations]
TIME:  0.7 Delta:  0.0 Mem:  77 G0:   0 G1:  0 G2:  0 [Encoding OptData]
TIME:  0.7 Delta:  0.0 Mem:  77 G0:   0 G1:  0 G2:  0 [TAST -> ILX]
TIME:  0.7 Delta:  0.0 Mem:  77 G0:   0 G1:  0 G2:  0 [ILX -> IL (Unions)]
TIME:  0.7 Delta:  0.0 Mem:  77 G0:   0 G1:  0 G2:  0 [ILX -> IL (Funcs)]

ilwrite: TIME      0.000 (total)        0.686 (delta) - Write Started
ilwrite: TIME      0.000 (total)        0.000 (delta) - Module Generation Preparation
ilwrite: TIME      0.000 (total)        0.000 (delta) - Module Generation Pass 1
ilwrite: TIME      0.000 (total)        0.000 (delta) - Module Generation Pass 2
ilwrite: TIME      0.016 (total)        0.016 (delta) - Module Generation Pass 3
ilwrite: TIME      0.016 (total)        0.000 (delta) - Module Generation Pass 4
ilwrite: TIME      0.016 (total)        0.000 (delta) - Finalize Module Generation Results
ilwrite: TIME      0.016 (total)        0.000 (delta) - Generated Tables and Code
ilwrite: TIME      0.016 (total)        0.000 (delta) - Layout Header of Tables
ilwrite: TIME      0.016 (total)        0.000 (delta) - Build String/Blob Address Tables
ilwrite: TIME      0.016 (total)        0.000 (delta) - Sort Tables
ilwrite: TIME      0.016 (total)        0.000 (delta) - Write Header of tablebuf
ilwrite: TIME      0.016 (total)        0.000 (delta) - Write Tables to tablebuf
ilwrite: TIME      0.016 (total)        0.000 (delta) - Layout Metadata
ilwrite: TIME      0.016 (total)        0.000 (delta) - Write Metadata Header
ilwrite: TIME      0.016 (total)        0.000 (delta) - Write Metadata Tables
ilwrite: TIME      0.016 (total)        0.000 (delta) - Write Metadata Strings
ilwrite: TIME      0.016 (total)        0.000 (delta) - Write Metadata User Strings
ilwrite: TIME      0.016 (total)        0.000 (delta) - Write Blob Stream
ilwrite: TIME      0.016 (total)        0.000 (delta) - Fixup Metadata
ilwrite: TIME      0.016 (total)        0.000 (delta) - Generated IL and metadata
ilwrite: TIME      0.016 (total)        0.000 (delta) - Layout image
ilwrite: TIME      0.016 (total)        0.000 (delta) - Writing Image
ilwrite: TIME      0.016 (total)        0.000 (delta) - Finalize PDB
ilwrite: TIME      0.016 (total)        0.000 (delta) - Signing Image
TIME:  0.7 Delta:  0.0 Mem:  78 G0:   0 G1:  0 G2:  0 [Write .NET Binary]
TIME:  0.7 Delta:  0.0 Mem:  78 G0:   0 G1:  0 G2:  0 [Write Stats File]
```